# Jquery complex multiple date selection plugin

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

The [default jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#default) is very handy. However, I would like to be able to select a single date, multiple dates or a periodic date. My requirements include:

- Ability to select a single date
- Ability to select 2 or more dates
- Ability to select a periodic date based on the days of the week. Eg: every monday between date A and date B
- Ability to have exceptions. Eg: every monday between date A and date B except for date C, D and E.

I want to know if such a Jquery plugin exists. I am also interested in a PHP plugin with the corresponding mysql structure for storing the dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some jQuery plugins you might want to look into

- http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html
- http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net
- http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiple.html